# Error: filter:notarray Not an array even when the syntax is correct

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to call an API but I get the Not an array error when I load the page. The data from the JSON isn't showing up.

This is the section of the code that has the issue:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
     <h4>TESTCASES</h4>
       <div ng-repeat="school in schools | filter: {selected: '!true'} track by $index">
         <span class="list-group-item" ng-click="school.status =!school.status" style="background-color:rgba(115,158,226,1);">{{school.name}}</span>
         <span class="list-group-item" ng-if="school.status" ng-repeat="subSchool in school.sub | filter: {selected: '!true'} track by $index" ng-click="select(subSchool)" tooltip= '{{subSchool.name}}, Run Time: {{subSchool.runTime}}'>{{subSchool.name}}</span>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h4>TEST PLAN</h4>
              <div class="list-group list-select">
                <span class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="school in selected track by $index" ng-click="deselect(school)">{{school.name}}</i></span>
              </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Try removing this : </i> in the line 4 from last

Comment: Is the API call succeeding? Are you getting the expected data back from the server? Is it being attached to scope correctly by your directive or controller?  We can't tell, because you haven't included any of the relevant code in the question.

Comment: I made some changes and got rid of this error but the new error now is : GET https://192.168.1.203:8080/atlasweb/enumTestCases net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

But when I directly enter the url for the JSON, I see it on the browser. It doesn't get called on the webpage when I call it from my code.

Comment: This is the updated code :

'use strict';
angular.module('app')
    .factory('apiSrv', function($http, $q, $resource) {

        var basePath = 'https://192.168.1.203:8080/atlasweb/';
        return {
            Test: $resource(basePath + "enumTestCases", null, {
                query: {
                    isArray: true,
                    cache: true
                }
            })
        }
    });